# Excel VBA: writing formula in current selection

Tags: excel, vba, selection, formula

I want to write the current month based on a referenced cell into the current selection. This is my code but I get the error message: object variable or with block variable not set. I don't know what the problem is - anyone have a clue?

```
Sub SelectionMonthNames()

Dim Currentrange As Range

For i = 1 To 3

    Currentrange = Selection.Address

    If i = 1 Then
        Currentrange.Formula = "=DATE(YEAR($B$5);MONTH($B$5);DAY($B$5))"
    Else
        Currentrange.Formula = "=DATE(YEAR($B$5);MONTH($B$5)+" & CStr(i - 1) & ";DAY($B$5))"
    End If

    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select

Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Set Currentrange = Selection.Address
```

Instead of

```
Currentrange = Selection.Address
```

**EDIT:**

So, final version of your macro should look like this:

```
Sub SelectionMonthNames()

Dim Currentrange As Range

For i = 1 To 3

Set Currentrange = Selection

If i = 1 Then
    Currentrange.Formula = "=DATE(YEAR($B$5),MONTH($B$5),DAY($B$5))"
Else
    Currentrange.Formula = "=DATE(YEAR($B$5),MONTH($B$5)+" & CStr(i - 1) &",DAY($B$5))"
End If

Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Range is an object and requires Set, unlike other variables.

Comment: Hi, now I get object required and it breaks at this line.

Comment: @user366121 Okay, Selection.Address is text, so use Selection.

Comment: And also, you used ';' as delimiters in formula and i'm pretty sure that you should use ','